# Express, Pug and Webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, pug-loader

I have a Node js server app which uses `Express` and `Pug`. I would like to bundle it to single script which can be deployed by `pm2`. There seem to be several problems with this.

1. In runtime I get `Cannot find module "."` and during compilation few messages like

> WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 80:29-41 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

appear which come from dynamic imports like `require(mod).__express`. I assume Webpack can't statically resolve those and does not know which dependency to include.

How can this be solved ?

2. How do I make `Pug` compile and be part of the output js ?

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Have you found how to do it ?

Comment: @ps-aux I am also in the same bot, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is because webpack rebundle `node_modules` (already bundled) dependencies and in the case of **pug**, it doesn't work.

You need to use [webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) within the webpack `externals` option in order to specifically ask not to re-bundle depedencies.

1. Install webpack-node-externals: `npm i -D webpack-node-externals`
2. Integrate it your webpack config file:

**Example**

```
// ...

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',

  entry: {
    // ...
  },

  module: {
    // ...
  },

  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  output: {
    // ...
  },
}
```